# how to upload a udp stream to AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, udp

I have a stream that only has udp protocol and I need to upload it to my AWS cloud server. Is it possible to send udp to the server if I don't have the stream in the local network of the AWS server? If possible, how should I do it?

Background:  I have a software that transcodes streams in the cloud (on an EC2). The problem is the following, I have a device that only produces a stream in UDP, and I don't know how to send it to the cloud transcoder. The problem is that UDP doesn't have access to the internet, so I can't think of how to upload it to the cloud.

Comment: We'd need more clarity and detail to help with this. Do you want to stream it to an EC2 server? What are you streaming from? Can you give us big  picture? Please edit your question to clarify.

Comment: HI 
The situation is the following, I have a software that transcodes streams in the cloud (on an EC2). The problem is the following, I have a device that only produces a stream in UDP, and I don't know how to send it to the cloud transcoder. The problem is that UDP doesn't have access to the internet, so I can't think of how to upload it to the cloud.   
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Are you saying your device doesn't have internet access, or that you don't think UDP works on the internet? Please edit your question to precisely describe your situation and problem so we can understand enough to help you.

Comment: I do have internet access, but I understand that UDP streams cannot be sent via the internet because packets are lost. Is it possible to send UDP Streams via internet?

Comment: UDP is an unreliable protocol compared with TCP, but it can travel across the internet. DNS is UDP, for example, though it falls back to TCP. If you need to have no errors or missed packets you'd need to work out a way to proxy it locally over to TCP.

Comment: Do you know of a way to convert udp to another format or something? ffmpeg doesn't work for me because I have to convert a live stream. Is there any software to convert a udp stream to something that doesn't lose packets over the internet?

Answer (score 0):

UDP works fine across the internet. There's a chance packets will be dropped, but with a stream that is usually not a deal breaker. If you MUST have a 100% accurate stream then you may have to work out a way to make it reliable. A VPN might be a good and fairly easy option, converting UDP to TCP would probably be difficult if it's possible.

Initially I suggest you send the UDP stream to your AWS instance. If it's not reliable enough I would then try setting up a VPN as that's a tunnel that might make UDP more reliable. AWS has a managed VPN service on their side, you can use any software or hardware you need on your side.

You could also stream to a local store then mirror / proxy / backup that to AWS with software such as rsync or a backup tool.

Comment: Thank you very muchhh.